# How to generate a script for changing a column of varchar to xml type with data being converted?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Initially I have a column (`partner_email`) of type `varchar`. Now a recent change has come where it needs to be changed to be changed to the `XML` datatype but the existing rows needs to be converted into the new column.

Help needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stepping through the scripts will help understand the problem:

**Script 1**

1. Use the Test database
2. If the column `partner_email_temp` does not exist in the Partner
   table, add `partner_email_temp` as an XML column
3. Update the Partner table. Change the value of `partner_email_temp` to
   be an XML-friendly string version of `partner_email`. Then convert it to XML. Use REPLACE to convert all & to the encoded &amp
4. Drop the column `partner_email` from Partner
5. Rename the column `partner_email_temp` to `partner_email`

All of this works the first time. When you run the script a second time, SQL Server gets to Step 2 and executes the ALTER TABLE statement again. This is because the column `partner_email_temp` does not exist (it was renamed in the first run to partner_email).

Now in step 3, you are attempting to update the `partner_email` column again. The problem is that this column is now an XML data type and your use of `REPLACE` is illegal. So SQL Server throws an error.

**Script 2**

1. Capture the column data type for the `partner_email` column in
   Partner.
2. If the column data type is varchar (meaning this is the first pass
   of the script),  execute the code in the BEGIN and END
3. If the column `partner_email_temp` does not exist, add the
   `partner_email_temp` column as an XML
4. Update the Partner table by changing the value of `partner_email_temp`
   to be an XML-friendly string version of `partner_email` and then
   convert it to XML. Use `REPLACE` to convert all & to the encoded &amp
5. Drop the column `partner_email` from Partner
6. Rename the column `partner_email_temp` to `partner_email`

The problem in the second script is that you cannot use the `GO` statement in your BEGIN and END statement.

According to [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx):

> SQL Server utilities interpret GO as a signal that they should send
>   the current batch of Transact-SQL statements to an instance of SQL
>   Server.

So in script 2, when SQL Server attempts to compile, it notices that the column `partner_email_temp` doesn't exist. It works in the Script 1 because the sections are executed separately. And when the portion that references `partner_email_temp` is executed, the column does exist.

So how do you fix it?

You can actually bypass all the dropping and renaming of columns if you simply update the data in the `partner_email` column to the correct format and then convert the column to an XML data type. This can be achieved in one SQL batch statement, but you need to execute it as dynamic SQL so that SQL Server will only try to execute the `REPLACE` statement when the `partner_email column` is a varchar data type:

```
IF NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
    WHERE table_name = 'Partner'
    AND   column_name = 'partner_email'
    AND   data_type = 'xml'
)
BEGIN

  DECLARE @sqlCmd NVARCHAR(4000)

  SET @sqlCmd = N' 
  UPDATE [dbo].[Partner]
  SET partner_email = ''<PartnerEmails><Email>'' 
  + REPLACE(partner_email, ''&'', ''&amp;'') 
  + ''</Email><Email></Email><Email></Email></PartnerEmails>'';
  ALTER TABLE Partner ALTER Column partner_email XML
  '

  EXEC (@sqlCmd) 

END
```